# Can I use SIFT based descriptors for aerial image classification?

Tags: sift

I am working on aerial RGB image classification. Can any expert kindly comment which descriptor would be better for fair classification? Gabor descriptors or SIFT descriptors?
Thanks much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, both features are OK, you can try both of them.

SIFT is usually used in normal image and aerial image, however, Gabor descriptor is more often applied to aerial image.

Check this paper[1] for more information.

[1]: Comparing SIFT descriptors and Gabor texture features for classification of remote sensed imagery, ICIP 2008